# Selenium Web Driver FindElement() method doesnt work(NoSuchElementException)

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

So my problem is simple. This is my code:

```
    driver.findElement(By.id("j_username")).sendKeys("nk");
    driver.switchTo().frame(0);
    driver.findElement(By.id("j_password")).sendKeys("1");
```

First findElement() method works correctly, but when im trying to use it in second time im getting this error:

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"j_password"}
```

All ids are correct.

Comment: Why are switching to frame? Is the second element in this frame?

Comment: You move to a frame. In the frame which driver is moved, exist element you try to find?

Comment: @AndreiSuvorkov No its not. I just added this because somebody told me that this will help but it didnt helped :)

Comment: Then delete it :). And check if it works. If not, please add a link to website or relevant HTML block

Comment: @AndreiSuvorkov deleting didnt helped. Here is HTML code `<tbody><tr><td>Логин:</td><td><input type="text" name="j_username" id="j_username" autocorrect="off" autocapitalize="off"></td></tr><tr><td>Пароль:</td><td><input type="password" name="j_password"></td></tr><tr><td align="right"><input id="remember_me" type="checkbox" name="remember_me"></td><td><label for="remember_me">Запомнить меня</label></td></tr></tbody>`

Comment: You don't need to move the frame if there is no frame. That mean the problem is at path of element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("j_username")).sendKeys("nk");
driver.findElement(By.name("j_password")).sendKeys("1"); // find by name
```

second element doesn't have id, at least in the `HTML` you have provided.

Comment: P.S.: You need to be sure there is not another element with `attribute name` `j_password`